# How to make right outer join?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am using OE schema and trying to see item # and quantity on hand in each warehouse and if any warehouse does not have item than it should show 0 item in hand. i am running following SQL and it is not showing 0 quantity for items.

```
select i.product_id,w.warehouse_name ,(i.quantity_on_hand)
from inventories i
right outer join warehouses w
on (i.warehouse_id=w.warehouse_id)
order by 1
```

I want to see result like this:

```
PRODUCT_ID WAREHOUSE_NAME                      NVL(I.QUANTITY_ON_HAND,0)
---------- ----------------------------------- -------------------------
  2262 Sydney                                                     35
  2262 Beijing                                                    50
  2262 Bombay                                                     35
  2262 San Francisco                                             155
  2262 Seattle, Washington                                        77
       Toronto                                                     0
       New Jersey                                                  0
       Southlake, Texas                                            0
       Mexico City                                                 0
  3501 Toronto                                                   220
  3501 Sydney                                                    320
  3501 Mexico City                                               294
  3501 Beijing                                                   268
  3501 San Francisco                                             353
       New Jersey                                                  0
       Southlake, Texas                                            0
       Seattle, Washington                                         0
       Bombay                                                      0
```

Comment: PREFERABLY SOLVE WITHOUT SHOUTING

Comment: It's an SQL thing, it seems ;-) SELECT shouting FROM stackoverflow;

Comment: Funnily, the query in the body is lowercase...

Answer (score 0):

You want to see a row for every warehouse and every product.  So, start with generating this list and use `left outer join` to bring in the values that exist:

```
select i.product_id, w.warehouse_name, coalesce(i.quantity_on_hand, 0)
from warehouses w cross join
     (select distinct product_id from inventories) p left join
     inventories i
     on w.warehouse_id = i.warehouse_id and p.product_id = i.product_id
order by i.product_id, w.warehouse_name;
```